# ObservedObject is still in memory after the view is dismissed, Memory Leak?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm making an app with SwiftUI and UIkit, I use UIkit for the main app controller and navigation, and I use SwiftUI for app design.

The app works very well, but I'm worried about the memory leaks. This is because the ViewModels I use to pass data between views don't call desinit whene the view disappears. I know that in SwiftUI views are not disposed immediately, but since I'm using UIKit to navigate I don't know what the problem is.

```
//The ViewModel for each user fetched
internal class UserViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    
    //MARK: - Propeties var currentListener: ListenerRegistration?
    
    @Published var request: Request?
    @Published var user: User
    
    init(user: User) {
        self.user = user
        getRequest()
        fetchAdmins()
    }
    
    deinit {
        //Dosnt get called removeListener()
    }
    
    func getRequest() {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
        guard let id = id else {return}
        
        self.currentListener = Collections.requests(id).document(uid).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
            
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            if ((snapshot?.exists) != nil) {
                if let request = try? snapshot!.data(as: Request.self) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.request = request
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func removeListener() {
        self.currentListener?.remove()
    }
}
}

//The ViewModel to fetch all the users ViewModels
class UsersViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users = [UserViewModel]()
    
    func fetch() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            Collections.users.getDocuments(completion: { snapshot, err in
                
                guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return } let users = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: User.self) })
                
                users.forEach { user in
                    let vm = UserViewModel(user: user)
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                        self.users.append(vm)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    } }

//Show the users cells with the ViewModel
struct HomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var usersViewModels: UsersViewModel
    
    //MARK: - Init
    init() {
        self.usersViewModels = UsersViewModel()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ListView(content: {
            ForEach(usersViewModels) { usersViewModel in
                UserCell(viewModel: usersViewModel).id(user.id)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This is how I navigate between controllers and views of my app. I don't use NavigationLinks:

```
    public static func push<Content: View>(view: Content) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
 guard let tabBarController = UIApplication.rootViewController as? UITabBarController, let navigationController = tabBarController.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController else { return nil }

            if let navigationController = UIApplication.getCurrentNavigationController() {
                navigationController.pushViewController(HostingController(content: view), animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know if this method that I am using to navigate can cause me memory problems? And you know why my app doesn't reduce its memory every time I close a window, it just increases more and more.

[image: Memory Leak Xcode Tool]

Comment: You probably (well, for sure) created a retain cycle in your view models where you capture `self` in a closure. For example, `self.request = request` in the callback for `addSnapshotListener`. Use a "capture list" to declare importing `self` weakly, i.e `something.async { [weak self] in self?.foobar() }`. For quick testing this measurement, just put a breakpoint in `deinit` and assert your expectations. Note that there's more to say about when you absolutely _need_ to weakly import a reference, when it is _optional_ causing certain consequences, and when it is not useful.

Comment: Next, absolutely avoid to publish an ObservableObject, instead publish only _plain old data_, i.e. structs and primitve types. You will run into issues when publishing reference objects, especially publishing objects conforming to ObservableObject.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Thanks, I already added the [weak self], but I have a question, in the case of
'@Published var users = [UserViewModel]()

Do you recommend that it be like this?:
'@Published var users = [User]()

Comment: Yes, exactly. Only publish Value Types, aka "Data", aka "Models". Publishing a _reference object_ will only get you change notification if that _reference_ would change and not when any properties of the current used reference will change. Well, you might want that rarely, but most likely not. ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Ok... but if I need to use the ViewModel to get more data and properties, can I initialize it inside the user cell?

Something like that:
    init(with user: User) {
        self.viewModel = UserViewModel(user: user)
    }

So that as soon as the user cell appears, all the functions of the UserViewModel begin to be executed

Comment: What I need is to be able to pass the ViewModel from the cell to the UserView, so that I don't have to fetch the ViewModel data for each View.

Comment: You only need two ViewModels, one obtainig a List of "User-Overview" and a second where you obtain a User-Detail when your "User-Detail" has richer properties than your "User-Overview". In that case, you pass the ID of a User from a common Parent-View -- which has Master-View and Detail-View as its children -- to the Detail-View which also may create the ViewModel loading a single Detail-User model. You may have a view settting up the ViewModel, but  then, you only pass the published data to its child view which renders the data.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Yes, but the problem is that when fetching the users I need to init the UserViewModel to be able to call functions like isFollowed(), this function is not only needed in the UserCell, I also need when navigating to the UserProfile from the UserCell the UserViewModel data is passed to know if you follow him or not. Btw thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: ‘@ObservedObjecg is when you get the object from parent view. Try declaring it as @StateObject if owned by the view.

Comment: Functions like `isFollowed()` should be performed by the ViewModel utilising an appropriate "Service". The VMs should provide an interface for `isFollowed(by: ID)` and expose them to the views, more precisely to a _certain_ view receiving this view model. This view then passes the function down as a closure variable to a child view which is responsible to handle the "Intent" of the user, i.e. handing the "Follow" button, where it calls this function in the action closure. So, ideally, a view does not know anything about Service or purpose if the "Intent", it just calls a function.

Comment: When you need to create non-shared ViewModel which does not need any initialisation parameters from some "Environment", just create it as StateObject in a view `@StateObject private var vm = VM()`. If you need parameters, prefer to read them from the Environment in which case you need a parent view which does read the env and then passes these parameters to the initialiser to the child view which creates the ViewModel. In contrast shared ViewModel can be created "outside" the view or in a parent view which passes them down to a child view which creates a ObservedObject from it.

Answer (score 0):

The disappearing does not mean it is no longer in memory.

It looks like you keep pushing them onto the navigation stack which increases their retain count.

Comment: How can i remove them from the navigation stack?

Comment: @SantiagoPadilla https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621886-popviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You've got a memory leak here:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var usersViewModels: UsersViewModel
    
    //MARK: - Init
    init() {
        self.usersViewModels = UsersViewModel() // here
    }
```

View structs must not init objects because the View struct is recreated every state change thus the object is being constantly init.

SwiftUI is all about taking advantage of value semantics, try to use `@State` with value types (or group them in a struct) in the `View` struct for your view data.

Model data structs go in a singleton `ObservableObject` supplied to the Views using `.environmentObject`.